# CreateFileMapping Issue with Parameter "Global\\MyMapping"

Tags: c++, winapi

I' using delphi on Win 7 with admin rights and while creating a Named Shared Memory i'm getting a strange error.

```
 hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
             INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
             NULL,                    // default security
             PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
             0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
             256,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
             "Global\\\MyMapping");                 // name of mapping object
```

When i use "Global\\MyMapping" it doesn't work and i get an error message
**could not create file mapping object (5)**.

But when i use "Global\MyMapping" it works fine.

**Question :** is there a specific reason why Delphi(Borland) given an error message when "Global\MyMapping"is used?

But the problem of "\\" and "\" does't come CreateMutex is used?

**Createmutex** works in both the cases :

First case code :

```
TCHAR szName1[]=TEXT("Global\\\NameOfMutexObject");
Mutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,szName1);
```

Second case code :

```
TCHAR szName1[]=TEXT("Global\NameOfMutexObject");
Mutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,szName1);
```

Regards,
Navneet

Comment: I can't make any sense of this.  All your code is C++. But you talk about Delphi. Do you know that you won't be able to create objects in the global namespace unless your process is elevated. We cannot see your error checking code. Perhaps you got that wrong. How about showing an MCVE.

Comment: I'm new on this site, in terms of asking questions. So please bear with me. I'm using C++ Builder 6. The main queston is CreateFileMapping with Parameter as "Global\\MyMapping" doesn't work and given an error message but CreateFileMapping with Parameter as "Global\MyMapping" works . I'm facing some difficulty in adding the code otherwise would have done so far.

Comment: OK, I removed the delphi tag. I have also answered the question

Answer (score 5):

It's documented for both [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CreateFileMutex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The name can have a "Global\" or "Local\" prefix to explicitly create
>   the object in the global or session namespace. The remainder of the
>   name can contain any character except the backslash character (\).

Your `CreateMutex` examples are not Delphi but C which uses backslash as an escape character. They create mutexes with the names (in Delphi notation) `'Global\'#10'ameOfMutexObject'` and `'Global'#10'ameOfMutexObject'`, respectively. (The sequence \n is interpreted in C as a line feed character, #10 in Delphi notation.)

Delphi doesn't use the backslash as an escape character so you should use an unescaped literal like `'Global\NameOfMutexObject'`.

Comment: You have not answered the reason why CreateFileMapping with Parameter as "Global\\MyMapping" doesn't work and given an error message but CreateFileMapping  with Parameter as "Global\MyMapping" works.

Comment: @NavneetThukral I think I have answered that. The prefix 'Global\' or 'Local\' is allowed. The rest may not contain a backslash. See the quote from the documentation above.

Comment: If you want to know why `CreateFileMapping` failed, check [`GetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as the documentation suggests. It could be that "Global\\MyMapping" already exists, you don't have sufficient permissions, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks TOndrej, it was permissions issue, But i still have one doubt,  Why we don't require the same permissions for creating Semaphore in Global Namespace. The statement Full=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,1,"Global\\Producer") works fine without giving admin rights as was required in case of CreateFileMapping.

Comment: Also when used the statement Mutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"Local\\NameOfMutexObject1");   it should technically create a Mutex in local Namespace and other Process shouldn't be able to access the Handle, but the other process works fine and can get the Handle. Same is the issue with Statement Mutex=CreateMutex(NULL,FALSE,"NameOfMutexObject1"); , the other process shouldn't be able to access it but it does and works fine.

Comment: Local namespace is accessible to all processes within the [session](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/07/24/sessions-desktops-and-windows-stations.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks TOndrej, just one last question :  Why we don't require the same permissions for creating Semaphore in Global Namespace. The statement Full=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,1,"Global\\Producer") works fine without giving admin rights but in case of CreateFileMapping admin rights were needed when CreateFileMapping was used with Parameter "Global\\MyMapping".

Comment: The documentation for [CreateSemaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says: _"If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the semaphore object. If the named semaphore object existed before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing object and GetLastError returns ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS."_ **Just guessing**: if the semaphore didn't already exist it would fail because of permissions; it succeeds because it already exists.

Answer (score 3):

> When I use "Global\\MyMapping" it doesn't work and I get an error message **could not create file mapping object (5)**.

Error code 5 is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Your process does not have sufficient rights to create an object in the global name space.

> But when I use "Global\MyMapping" it works fine.

That's because with `\M` the backslash is an escape character and not a back space. Hence you are creating an object in the local name space which does not require elevated rights.

Comment: Thank for the response David, i get the point that i was creating the File Mapping in the local Namespace. If that is the case then other Process shouldn't have been able to access the File Mapping, but i tried and it worked fine. 2 process were able to communicate when hMapFile = CreateFileMapping was created with Parameter "Global\MyMapping", If 2 processes can communicate then why use Global Namespace.

Comment: The global name space is shared between sessions. You use it if you want to create an object that can be seen by a process in a different session. Two processes in the same session can see objects in the local namespace. That's why MS refer to it as the session namespace. The documentation describes is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Many thanks David, just one last question :  Why we don't require the same permissions for creating Semaphore in Global Namespace. The statement Full=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,1,"Global\\Producer") works fine without giving admin rights but in case of CreateFileMapping admin rights were needed when CreateFileMapping was used with Parameter "Global\\MyMapping".

Answer (score 0):

Open Command Prompt as Administrator and run your program or set "Local" in the path instead of "Global"